# Spark: Testing Memory usage locally

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

My spark program running on aws ec2 instances crashes due to running out of memory (error below).  In order to select the appropriate ec2 instance type and size, I would like to run the program locally and test it's memory usage.  Is this possible?

To **image description here**

[image]